# Add samples to database python

Tags: python, database, dataframe, append

I'd like to build a database which stores lists of values, categorized by two properties.

In my case the 2 values are coordinates. (lat & lng), and the values are distances that are saved in a particular sample.

My model generates samples in pandas dataframes with +/- 40 rows, 1 column indicates the lat, 1 column indicates the lng and the third column indicates the savings. Both lat and lng are fixed (brackets of locations). For each, i have 100 options... (10,000 unique combinations in total). of which per sample 40 locations are randomly drawn (in theory possible twice the same in 1 sample)

I'd now like to store this data by saving list for every combinations of lat&lng. Basicly appending each savings value to the lat&lng list it belongs in.

(As a bonus, it would be nice to add the sample number it came from, so its origin in tracable... but not strictly required)

Comment: Are you trying to build a db schema like in MySQL/Postgres or do you want this all in Pandas?

Comment: I'm using pandas atm. never heard of a db schema... will look in to that. I do have to stick with python but i don't mind if it is a pandas df, dict. or list of lists etc.

Comment: I think pandas would suffice. I am the only user, i generate the sample in the python script itself, just need to transfer/merge/aggregate it somehow. In the end the goal is to get averages for each location (combination of lat&lng)